# how do I switch from 1 wireless network to other automatically

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

In the network and internet settings section, all the available networks are displayed. How do I switch from one secured wireless network to other automatically incase the previous connected network is weak or lost?

Answer (score 1):

### Windows 7

1. **Left click** on **wifi icon** on the right of the taskbar.
2. **Right click** the network you want to automatically connect to and select **properties**.
3. In the **Connection** tab, make sure that **connect automatically when in range** is checked.

### Windows 10

1. Open **Settings**.
2. Click on **Network & Security**.
3. Click on **Wi-Fi**.
4. Click the **Wi-Fi** connection.
5. Turn on the **Connect automatically when in range** option.

With both Windows 7 & 10 will the connection switch automatically whenever the first connection goes down.